# Syntax error in a guard causing undefined function

Tags: erlang, undefined, guard

I have no idea what is the problem,
this is the code-

```
solve_bdd(BddTree, ListVars) ->
  findRes(BddTree, maps:from_list(ListVars++[{one, 1}, {zero, 0}])).
findRes(BddTree, Map) when is_record(BddTree, node)-> Val = maps:get(getName(BddTree)), Name = getName(BddTree),
  if Name=='one' or Name=='zero' -> maps:get(getName(BddTree));
     (Val==1 or Val=='true') -> findRes(getRight(BddTree), Map);
     (Val==0 or Val=='false') -> findRes(getLeft(BddTree), Map);
     true -> error
  end;
findRes(_, _) -> error.
```

And the shell errors-

```
exf.erl:183: syntax error before: '=='
exf.erl:180: function findRes/2 undefined
exf.erl:21: Warning: function getRight/1 is unused
exf.erl:22: Warning: function getLeft/1 is unused
error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there is multiple conditions, You should group operands of `or` operator in parentheses:

```erlang
1> false or false.
false

2> false == true or false == true.
* 1: syntax error before: '=='

2> (false == true) or (false == true).
false
```

Also `maps:get/1` (function `get` in module `maps` which accepts 1 parameter) that you used:

```erlang
maps:get( getName(BddTree) )
```

does not exists! But you can use `maps:get/2` or `maps:get/3`.

Most of the time you can use `case` expression instead of `if` expression.
Also sometimes it's better to use `orlese` operator instead of `or`.
It's better to not handle anything! instead of handling both `0` and `1` and boolean types, you can use one of them and remove unnecessary checks.
By convention in Erlang it's better to write function and record names in [Snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

BTW, your `findRes/2` function would be like:

```erlang
%%% I don't know what work you expect from this function so if it's not working
%%% just like your own, try to fix it!  

% findRes -> find_res
find_res(BddTree, Map) when is_record(BddTree, node) ->
  % Sounds like BddTree is a record. If by `get_name/1` you just want to
  % access one of it's elements, you can simply write BddTree#node.<ELEMENT_NAME>
  % getName -> get_name
  case get_name(BddTree) of
    % you don't have to use ' character for atoms:
    Name when Name == one orelse Name == zero ->
      % I thinkd you've missed `Map`:
      maps:get(get_name(BddTree), Map);
    _ -> 
      % I do not use 0 and 1 and just use boolean type:
      find_res(
        % I thinkd you've missed `Map`:
        case maps:get(get_name(BddTree), Map) of
          Val when Val -> % when Val == true
            % getRight -> get_right
            get_right(BddTree);
          _ -> % Assume false
            get_left(BddTree)
        end,
        Map
      )
  end;

find_res(_, _) -> error.
```

And let's look at above code without comments:

```erlang
find_res(BddTree, Map) when is_record(BddTree, node) ->
  case get_name(BddTree) of
    Name when Name == one orelse Name == zero ->
      maps:get(get_name(BddTree), Map);
    _ -> 
      find_res(
        case maps:get(get_name(BddTree), Map) of
          Val when Val -> % when Val == true
            get_right(BddTree);
          _ ->
            get_left(BddTree)
        end,
        Map
      )
  end;
find_res(_, _) -> error.
```